# MySQL advanced select syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I have been told in workplace that i have to upgreade our e-shop script, provide users ability to select language of their choice. Until now we had just one language and from now on we will be having 4 of them with possibility of expanding. So i have to design engine that easly allows to add more languages and use them right away without further coding.

Problem im having regards MySQL syntax structure to accomplish what i was told to.

Our current script starts with: `SELECT *` and this has to change. For now i came up with this code:

```
"SELECT
id,
name_" . Config::get('current/language') . " as name,
description_" . Config::get('current/language') . " as description,
configurations_" . Config::get('current/language') . " as configurations,
images,
price_" . Config::get('current/language') . " as price,
shipping_" . Config::get('current/language') . " as shipping,
instock,
ready";
```

The reason behind this idea of mine is that i dont have to alter entire service, MySQL syntax is provided with whatever language has been selected and sending common names without language affix to application therefore it will always work and be fine. However asteriks was convenient in the way that whatever new row in the db structure has been added it was usable right away without any coding. So my question is, is it possible to keep asteriks in the syntax for all rows extraction but still use above code for fields that require language affix? Something like:

`SELECT * (however for field 'name' use this code 'name_" . Config::get('current/language') . " as name')`

Thank you for all help:)

Comment: Using asterix in production code is considered a bad practice, so naming your columns is not a negative aspect of your change here. Also, your argument in favor is a false one: `whatever new row in the db structure has been added it was usable right away without any coding.` -> without writing the column in the query, yes, but you'll need coding afterwards to do something with the data anyway.

Comment: Well thats true actually havent thought about it, so you say that the way it is atm is completely fine and i should keep it that way?

Comment: Your suggested solution would require major table changes when a new language was added to the site. Further it provides no way to fall back to a default language should the details of a product in a selected language have not yet been populated. Best to normalise your data, and do as @Konerak suggests below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd put all the text that needs translation in a **different table**, and JOIN the two tables on ID, language.

```
SELECT id, name,description,configurations,images,price,shipping,instock,ready
FROM yourtable
JOIN tablewithtranslations
ON yourtable.id = tablewithtranslations.id 
AND tablewithtranslations.language = " . Config::get('current/language')
```

The JOIN clause will select the right rows in the translations table. Adding a new language is just adding new rows in the translations table.